# One Sql Server Deadlock issue: exclusive lock wait on update lock

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

met the following problem about deadlock, don't know whey this happens, need help, thanks!
Here is what happens(the simplified version).

I have the following table and indexes:

```
    --Create table JobMaster

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JobMaster](
        [JobId] uniqueidentifier,
        [CreateTime] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()),\
        [JobStatus] INT NULL, 
        [JobStatusUpdateTime] DATETIME NULL, 
[DataUploadStatus] int,
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED([JobId])     
    )
    GO

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX index_jobMaster_createtime ON [dbo].[JobMaster]([CreateTime])
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_jobMaster_jobStatus ON [dbo].[JobMaster]([JobStatus])
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_jobMaster_jobStatusUpdateTime ON [dbo].[JobMaster]([JobStatusUpdateTime])
    GO
```

And we have a dead lock on three sessions:
Deadlock:
 A ->(wait for resource holding by) B -> C -> A.

A and C holding the update lock on JobMaster with index PK (non-cluster), and session B holding the X lock on JobMaster with cluster index

Here is the operation for A/B/C(Read committed isolation level, no special setting):
A/B:

```
UPDATE [JobMaster] SET 
    [DataUploadStatus] = 1,e
    WHERE JobId= 'E6AEE804-6A09-4293-B93C-15E9748E46ED'
```

C:

```
UPDATE [JobMaster] SET [JobStatus] = 1,
 [JobStatusUpdateTime] = GETUTCDATE() 
WHERE JobId= 'E6AEE804-6A09-4293-B93C-15E9748E46ED'
```

My question is:

1. Why does session B wait on the U lock of jobmaster on pk index hold by A, while B is holding the X lock on clustered index? I mean since B has the X lock, which is lock to update the clustered index, seems it has no other locking needs?
2. What is the sequence of lock request/release on the three sessions? My understanding is, like for session B: update lock on JobMaster with PK and JobMaster with cluster index, then the X lock on JobMaster with Cluster index. Correct me if I am wrong.
3. Since we don't modify the non-cluster indexes, in any of the queries. Why do they need a U lock on the index? And why C is waiting for A, as C already have the U lock.

Comment: If you are experiencing deadlock errors, turn on trace flag 1222. It will log the deadlock errors to the SQL server log. (see http://sqlindian.com/2012/07/06/troubleshooting-deadlocks/ and http://www.togsblom.com/2008/12/basic-sql-server-deadlock-debugging.html)

Comment: thanks, this is just what I summarized from the xdl.

Comment: Please post the execution plans, not just a picture of them.  The images alone don't tell us very much.

Comment: Please post the content of xdl. And, as RBarryYoung suggests, you should add the execution plans (XML format).